# Get-ChildItem Recursive Search on Specific Child Path

Tags: powershell

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered or the answer is staring at my right in the face but I'm not sure I'm asking it correctly to find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm looking to search through user directories using PowerShell to extract a specific line from an ini file (clean up from poor record keeping from an old admin).

What I want to do to reduce the time of the search (a lot of directories to run through) as well as I would like to split my result set based on the Production and Test ini file I'm looking for.

Here is what the folder structure looks like:

For Production:

```
E:\Users\<username>\DIR\production.ini
```

For Test:

```
E:\Users\<username>\DIR\Test\test.ini
```

So I want to run something like this (at the root of E:):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ".\DIR\*.ini" | Select-String "DeviceName="
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path ".\DIR\Test\*.ini" | Select-String "DeviceName="
```

That way it looks into each user's folder for the exact path instead of recursing through all the child folders.  I need to wildcard the ini as there are 2 - 3 possible files depending on the version of the application they are running.

Thanks as always for the assist.

Comment: If you're using the PowerShell version 5 or newer you might want to consider using `ConvertFrom-StringData` which is a new cmdlet added for exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If you don't want to recurse, just don't use the `-recurse` switch?

Comment: I think you are searching for something like `Get-ChildItem E:\Users\*\*.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper formatting makes the question legible unhiding the `<UserName>` etc.

Depending on your PoSh version use either `-Directory` or `|where $_.PSIsContainer` to first iterate the userFolders and then directly check the two possible folders.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Users -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ChildItem -Path "$($_.FullName)\Dir"      -Filter *.ini -EA 0 |Select-String "DeviceName="
  Get-ChildItem -Path "$($_.FullName)\Dir\Test" -Filter *.ini -EA 0 |Select-String "DeviceName="
}
```

To suppress errors I included the abbrev. `-EA 0` for `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: Thank you, this gets me to where I need to be.  I apologize for not being clear in my question about <username>.  I meant to indicate that was a place holder for each users username and needed to be iterated over.  The idea being that I didn't want to recurse through the full users directory just through the root of the E:\User folder.

Much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the item name and path, I'd suggest just using `Get-Item` in `GCI`'s stead.